# 301 Redirect All Blog Posts To New Subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I am currently using this .htaccess rewrite to get pretty urls for my blog posts:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /item.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

This ends up looking like:

> example.com/my-new-awesome-blog-post

What I would like is to move all my posts to a new folder called **items** so that it would look like:

> example.com/items/my-new-awesome-blog-post

I not only want to move all blog posts to the subfolder, but also to ensure it is a proper 301 redirect so there is no issue with SEO.

Thank you for your help/advice.

Comment: Would you move `item.php` file also inside `/items/` directory?

Comment: Ya I can do that as long as it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+items/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ items%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^items/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ items/item.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```